# Issue with connecting R file to python with a dynamic path.

Tags: python, r, flask, rpy2

The way you connect an external r_test.r file to a python code (running an r file through python using rpy2) is in the way given below.

```
r('''    source('r_test.r')
    ''')
```

This did not work in my flask application. So I tried getting the full url and using the same function

```
r('''    source('/Users/flyn/...../some_flask_app/scr/Configuration/app/api/scripts/r_test.r')
    ''')
```

This worked. Now to make this dynamic I tried this.

```
global_loc = global_loc = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
r_loc = global_loc+'/r_test.r'
r('''    source(r_loc)
    ''')
```

This didn't work. It threw an error:  'object 'r_loc' not found'.
So my question is, 
 **1. How will I be able to pass the string to the r(''' ''') segment? 
 2. Is there a better way to handle this entire problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using format

```
source = '''     source({})    '''.format(r_loc)
r(source)
```

not sure about question 2.

Comment: That worked. Small edit necessary. The quotes inside source.
source = '''     source('{}')    '''.format(r_loc)
r(source)